# poi cannot write data into .xlsx

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

the problem is when I tried to write data into cells, the cell either hasn't been created or it just doesn't show the data in it.

For instance,

```
Row[] rownames = new Row[names.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
    rownames[i] = sheet.createRow(i+3);
    Cell machine = rownames[i].createCell(0);
    machine.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    machine.setCellValue(names.get(i).toString());
}
```

`names[]` is an array that contains a list of names.

`Cell machine = rownames[i].createCell(0);` creates a cell at (i+3,0), in which i means row.

`machine.setCellValue(names.get(i).toString());` sets cell value to the corresponding name[i].

I tried print `names[]` and `machine.getStringCellValue()`, and both of them can return the exact correct data (like output to console). but there's nothing in xlsx file. many thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Let me explain more clearly, so if everything goes well, the very part of this xlsx file should be like this:

`harry   |    (row 3, col 0)
kate    |    (row 4, col 0)
jim     |    (row 5, col 0)
aaron   |    (row 6, col 0)
...
...`

But now the situation is:

`|    (row 3, col 0)
        |    (row 4, col 0)
        |    (row 5, col 0)
        |    (row 6, col 0)
...
...`

Right now the xlsx is 4KB. it contains some other information, which have been put there via this very program. Those parts don't have this problem.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you saying that the .xslx file that you generate is zero bytes long? If that's the problem you need to show the code that saves the .xlsx file.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I updated the question, please take look at it if I made myself understood. many thanks.

Comment: How do you reuse `rownames[]` array?

Comment: @dlopatin right, I used the same row index rather than the exact `rownames[]`, it's the same. your solution totally solved this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you create row by same index multiple times in further (non posted) code.

How poi creates `XSSFRow`:

```
public XSSFRow createRow(int rownum) {
    CTRow ctRow;
    XSSFRow prev = _rows.get(rownum);
    if(prev != null){
        // the Cells in an existing row are invalidated on-purpose, in order to clean up correctly, we
        // need to call the remove, so things like ArrayFormulas and CalculationChain updates are done 
        // correctly. 
        // We remove the cell this way as the internal cell-list is changed by the remove call and 
        // thus would cause ConcurrentModificationException otherwise
        while(prev.getFirstCellNum() != -1) {
            prev.removeCell(prev.getCell(prev.getFirstCellNum()));
        }

        ctRow = prev.getCTRow();
        ctRow.set(CTRow.Factory.newInstance());
    }
    ...
}
```

So, if row exists and contains cell, all cells with data will be removed.

To avoid this, use `CellUtil` class:

- > Get a row from the spreadsheet, and create it if it doesn't exist.

  ```
  CellUtil.getRow(rowIndex, sheet);
  ```
- > Get a specific cell from a row. If the cell doesn't exist, then create it.

  ```
  CellUtil.getCell(row, columnIndex);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted file opening and closing code. Based on description, it seems that you are not writing data back to Excel file. Do something like this:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("path of excel file"));
    wb.write(out);
    wb.close();
   out.close();
```

After executing entire code, then check excel file for the output generated.

Comment: `Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  outputdata(wb);
  File outputfile = new File(outputfilename);
  FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
  wb.write(fileout);
  fileout.close();`  This is the code to output. I don't think it's the reason cause some other information output correctly. @mk08

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
```

This is my code...

```
        HSSFFont boldFont; 
        HSSFFont bodyFont; 

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("namefile");
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);

        //HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();      
        //cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);

       //cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LAVENDER.index);
        //cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);


        row.setHeightInPoints(23);

        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)0, (short)2000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)1, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)2, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)3, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)4, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)5, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)6, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)7, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)8, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)9, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)10, (short)3000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth((short)11, (short)3000);

        row.createCell((short)0).setCellValue("FLT NO");
        row.createCell((short)1).setCellValue("LEG");
        row.createCell((short)2).setCellValue("DATE");
        row.createCell((short)3).setCellValue("AC-REG");
        row.createCell((short)4).setCellValue("SCHED DEP");
        row.createCell((short)5).setCellValue("OFFBLK");
        row.createCell((short)6).setCellValue("AIRBORNE");
        row.createCell((short)7).setCellValue("LANDING");
        row.createCell((short)8).setCellValue("ONBLK");
        row.createCell((short)9).setCellValue("SCHED ARR");
        row.createCell((short)10).setCellValue("FUEL_USED_PILOT");
        row.createCell((short)11).setCellValue("ACTUAL FUEL");      


        ProofSheetFPRModel model = new ProofSheetFPRModel();
        int rownum = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<DataList.size(); i++) 
        {
            model = DataList.get(i);
            row = sheet.createRow((short)rownum);
            row.createCell((short)0).setCellValue(model.getFlightNo());
            row.createCell((short)1).setCellValue(model.getLEG());
            row.createCell((short)2).setCellValue(model.getDate());
            row.createCell((short)3).setCellValue(model.getAC_REG());
            row.createCell((short)4).setCellValue(model.getSCHED_DEP());
            row.createCell((short)5).setCellValue(model.getOFF_BLK());
            row.createCell((short)6).setCellValue(model.getAIRBORNE());
            row.createCell((short)7).setCellValue(model.getLANDG());
            row.createCell((short)8).setCellValue(model.getON_BLK());
            row.createCell((short)9).setCellValue(model.getSCHED_ARR());
            row.createCell((short)10).setCellValue(model.getFUEL_USED_PILOT());
            row.createCell((short)11).setCellValue(model.getACTUAL_FUEL());
            rownum++;
        }

        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem that the OP is having?

Comment: @Cherryishappy you mean I shouldn't use row array to create cell or I should use `(short)`? I've tried those before, those didn't help.